# How do I produce synthetic data over a specified range in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with three variables: a, b, and c. I am plotting each variable against the other (making plots a vs. b, a vs. c, and b vs. c), but I would like to produce synthetic data in the negative space of all of these plots. For example, in the figure below, I would like to produce a cloud of data within the confines of the red region for each plot. The goal would then be to concatenate these data to my original DataFrame. Do you have any suggestions as to how to do this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

-Zack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the images it seems that you want data points `(a, b, c)` such that at most one of `a`, `b`, `c` may be larger than zero.

Here's a brute-force solution: we randomly sample numbers (between `lower_boundary` and `upper_boundary`) for `a`, `b` and `c`, but we only consider the sample valid if at most one of its values is positive. We repeat this until we have `N` valid samples:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lower_boundary = -10
upper_boundary = 10
N = 1000

results = []
while len(results) < N:
    sample = np.random.uniform(lower_boundary, upper_boundary, size=3)
        if (sample > 0).sum() <= 1:  # if sample is valid
            results.append(sample)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

`df` is:

```
            a         b         c
0    6.708042 -6.296763 -4.611970
1   -2.766584 -8.684907 -1.333156
2   -3.994917 -8.713406 -6.340977
3   -7.923463 -9.884595 -4.459542
4   -6.278565 -7.842154  9.276437
..        ...       ...       ...
995 -1.522841 -3.527196  3.288719
996 -9.001377 -0.122435  9.962028
997 -2.906317  2.199631 -2.110314
998 -4.994767 -5.699236 -0.215391
999 -3.183467 -7.262613  4.581943

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: One thing I noticed, is that this preferentially fills the third quadrant. Would there be an easy way to make it more even between the second, third and fourth quadrants? Thanks!